# Get rid of Mail VIP list

Tags: macos, email

I upgraded to Mountain Lion a couple of months ago. But only just today did the VIP mailbox show up in Mail. I'd like to get rid of it. But apparently there is no way to get rid of it.

But that seems odd, since it only first showed up today, for no reason I can discover. For some reason it had an "Angieslist" subfolder, but with nothing in it.

Very odd. Annoying too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What most likely happened is, somehow, you clicked on a star icon which appears just to the right of the senders name. I've done this myself, more than once, thinking it was a bookmark / favorite button.

That star sets the sender as a VIP – an easy way to filter emails from important contacts, which is really what the VIP under the hood.

The reason it was empty is, I assume, because there were no Angielist emails in your inbox.

To remove, and I'm assuming you found this already, is by control-clicking on the name in the VIP list and selecting Remove VIP. Restart Mail once and the VIP sidebar item should be gone for good.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all VIPs if there are any.
2. Make sure *VIP* folder is not the current one. Otherwise restarting Mail won't help.
3. Restart Mail.

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought that quitting Mail and restarting would get rid of the VIP folder. So I tried that several times. No luck.

However, eventually after quitting Mail for the n-th time, after restarting it, the VIP folder has finally disappeared on its own.

So it seems the way to get rid of it is to get rid of all of the sub-folders, then quit and restart Mail n times.

So I am thinking this might be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the mailboxes
2. Click on VIP mailbox (it will show the VIP senders)
3. Control-Click on each VIP sender's star and remove it
4. When last sender is removed the mailbox disappears